# React Native Base Button fontSize not working

Tags: react-native, native-base

I'm using the React Native Base [Button](https://docs.nativebase.io/button).

The `fontSize` prop doesn't seem to work at all, it doesn't do anything. Am I doing something wrong, or misunderstanding the prop?

I did install the library using `--legacy-peer-deps`, because it doesn't offically support React 18 yet, but it seems to be working fine outside of this.

Comment: I think that they use `size` prop instead. try it out

Comment: @Alen.Toma I've tried that, it increases the font size slightly, but mainly changes the button size, and it has less values it accepts than the normal fontSize (e.g. on Text)

Comment: And in commenting that, I realized I can just put a Text inside the button. However, it doesn't inherit the button color, and I wonder if it impacts accessibility?

Comment: Adding text should work and make it background transparent. It should not have any issue with  accessibility. You have to try though.

Comment: I found an alternative solution, posting it now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears you can pass props to the underlying `Text` in the `Button` with the `_text` prop:

```
<Button _text={{fontSize: "2xl"}}> 
  Press Me
</Button>
```

Comment: `_text` seems a private prop, expect it that it may be removed in the future.

Comment: @Alen.Toma why would you say that? I asked in the library's discord, and that's what they suggested (after I figured it out). I think they just use underscores as the pattern for referencing internal components.

Comment: Yep and that is why I said it may be removed changed etc as it is not meant for user to use. So just keep a look out when you update the library.

Comment: It's part of the interface in [the documentation](https://docs.nativebase.io/button). I hear what you're saying, but I think underscore props are intended to be stable in this library. Of course, anything could change in the future.

Comment: Aha I see in that case good work finding the prop

Answer (score -1):

You are trying to increase Button's font size that is why it is not working. Think about that you try to increase TouchableOpacity's font size.
Here is a possible Solution

```
    <Button>
     <Text style={{fontSize:16}} >Button Title</Text>
    </Button>
```